# The abstract environment changes the \linewidth for the whole document

Tags: environments, indentation, abstract

In the article class, it seems that using the `abstract` environment has an effect to the rest of the document. More precisely, it seems that it redefines the `\linewidth`, which equals `\textwidth` without `abstract`, is smaller with the `abstract`. My feeling is that `\linewidth` is redefined for the `abstract` environment, but the value is not reseted at the end of the `abstract`.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\abstract{This is an abstract. This is an abstract.}\bigskip

This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text.\\ 
\rule{\textwidth}{3em}
\rule{\linewidth}{3em}
\end{document}
```

The output is not the same if you comment the `\abstract` line or not.

Do you have the same problem as I do when you compile (if not, I will upload some PDF files to show)? Is this a (known) bug in LaTeX2e? How can we circumvent the problem?

Note: I compile with the pdflatex command, and I use pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian).

Comment: What if I want to intentionally keep the linewidth the same for the rest of the document, but use correct syntax, i.e. `\begin{abstract} This is an abstract. This is an abstract. \end{abstract}`? Is there a way of knowing the linewidth used in the abstract? -> See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102769/the-abstract-environment-changes-the-line-width-for-the-whole-document-nice-bu)!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`abstract` is an environment and should be used as such. And `\linewidth` is smaller than `\textwidth` within `abstract` because `abstract` (without `article`'s `titlepage` class option) is based on the `quotation` environment which adds left-hand and right-hand indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
This is an abstract. This is an abstract.
\end{abstract}

\bigskip

This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text.\\ 
\rule{\textwidth}{3em}
\rule{\linewidth}{3em}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Usually I use the environment, I do not know why this time I did not! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Bruno: There is only the environment, but all environments are implemented using internal macros with the same name and an end macro which starts with 'end', i.e. \abstract and \endabstract. Therefore your original code still compiled without warning or error, but lead to a wrong result.

Comment: The worst part is that *theoretically*, I know all of what you remind me... I should have think about it a bit longer. Yet, if my question and lockstep's answer can help some other people, it was not a waste of time!