# Including abstract reduces the number of pages

Tags: abstract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The abstract environment changes the \linewidth for the whole document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25833/the-abstract-environment-changes-the-linewidth-for-the-whole-document)

I would like to know why when I introduce an abstract to my paper of (article type), the number of pages decreases, possibly changing the characters size.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example document where this happens?

Comment: @Jake Oh I think I know why, I was using `\abstract{}` and I think I should use instead `\begin{abstract}{}
\end{abstract}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `article` class defines the abstract as **environment**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
  The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

The implementation of environments defines two commands `\abstract` for the `\begin` code and `\endabstract` for the `\end` code. Also a grouping level is inserted by `\begin` and `\end`.
If you call `\abstract` directly, then the grouping level is missing and the begin code of environment `abstract` uses `\small` that remains active for the following text.