# Change linewidth for the whole document, while keeping fancyhdr wide?

Tags: fancyhdr, width, abstract

Somebody noticed that `\abstract` changes the linewidth for the whole document ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25833/the-abstract-environment-changes-the-linewidth-for-the-whole-document)).

The problem was the syntax: with correct syntax as below this is avoided.

```
\begin{abstract} 
This is an abstract. This is an abstract. 
\end{abstract}
```

while this keeps the linewith for the rest of the document:

```
\abstract
This is the abstract
```

But what if I want to intentionally keep the linewidth the same for the rest of the document, but use correct syntax? Is there a way of knowing the linewidth used in the abstract and setting it manually? This is interesting, if one uses the `fancyhdr`package, and one wants the headers be wider than the text.

Comment: `changepage` package provides an environment `adjustwidth` which uses different margins than the rest of the document. I guess you can enclose the whole document in that environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase margins by `0.35in`, and add a `\fancyhfoffset[L,R]{0.35in}`. The latter makes the fancyheader sticking 0.35 inches into the margins.

The only problem left is the abstract, which has to be sorted out manually, by making it looking like original.

```
\documentclass[fleqn, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1.5in,bottom=1.5in,left=1.35in,right=1.35in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{mcode} % for Matlab code

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt} % use \pagestyle{fancy} to activate
\lhead{Lorem ipsum }    \lfoot{dolor sit amet} % \lhead[lh-even]{lh-odd}    \lfoot[lf-even]{lf-odd}
\chead{ }   \cfoot{ } % \chead[ch-even]{ch-odd}     \cfoot[cf-even]{cf-odd}
\rhead{Ut purus elit}   \rfoot{\thepage} % \rhead[rh-even]{rh-odd}  \rfoot[rf-even]{rf-odd}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhfoffset[L,R]{0.35in}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy} 


\small
\begin{center}
\bfseries Abstract \vspace{.5em}
\end{center}
    \lipsum[1]
\normalsize
```

Answer (score 1):

`abstract` is typeset internally using `quotation` environment. I guess you can put your whole document inside a `quotation`, except for the abstract, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\title{The title}
\author{The Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
  \begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
  \end{abstract}

\begin{quotation}
  \section{First}
  \lipsum[2]

  \section{Second}
  \lipsum[3]
  \lipsum[4]
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Foo
    \item Bar
  \end{itemize}
  \lipsum[5]
\end{quotation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

But probably floats will still use the real margins.

Answer (score 1):

It can simply be done using the TeX primitives `\leftskip` and `\rightskip`

```
    \leftskip2.5em
    \rightskip\leftskip
```

Internally that is how lists are built (in a much more complicated way) based on `trivlist`.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\title{The title}
\author{The Author}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
  \begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
  \end{abstract}

\section{One}

\leftskip2.5em
\rightskip\leftskip

  \lipsum[3]
  \lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```