# Article abstract affects indent in the whole document

Tags: indentation, abstract

Using the `abstract` environment in my article seems to affect the whole document in regard to indentation. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % sets indent to zero
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt} % changes vertical space between paragraphs

\begin{document}

\abstract{Test test test}

\section{Test}

Test

Test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As you say: `abstract` is an environment, but you use it as if it were a command. The correct use is `\begin{abstract} <abstract text> \end{abstract}` instead of `\abstract{<abstract text>}`. Indeed thanks to the way environments are implemented `\abstract{blurgh}` starts the abstract environment, but it does not end thus changing the indentation of the entire document.

Comment: duplicate: [The abstract environment changes the \linewidth for the whole document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25833/579)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `article` document class, `abstract` is an environment, and so it should be used as follows.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % sets indent to zero                                
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt} % changes vertical space between paragraphs          

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Test test test
\end{abstract}

\section{Test} 
Test Test
\end{document}
```